# How to create an empty list?

Tags: r, list

Here is a code (**also see comments in code**):

```
library(rlist)

lwa_res_lst <- vector(mode = "list", length = 1) # Create empty list. Unfortunatly with this method I cannot create list with 0 length.
current_res <- 1
  
lwa_res_lst <- list.append(lwa_res_lst, current_res)  # Append the element at the end of the list.
```

**My question is:** How to initially create empty list to which after can be appended an element with `list.append()` at position `1`?

Comment: this function is just `c`: `c(list(), 1)` or `c(NULL, list(1))` will give you the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just do assignment

```
lwa_res_list[[1]] <- current_res
```

---

In the OP's code, if the `list` was initialized as

```
lwa_res_lst <- list()
```

Or using OP's code

```
lwa_res_lst <- vector(mode = "list", length = 0)
```

the code should work

```
lwa_res_lst <- list.append(lwa_res_lst, current_res) 
lwa_res_lst
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current_res <- 1  #any number you want for list

lwa_res_lst <- vector(mode = "list", length = current_res)

lwa_res_lst


class(lwa_res_lst)
```